# How do you remove all elements in a 2D array using pop function

Tags: python

Say I have this code:

```
Num = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

And I would like to output this:

```
[ [],[],[] ]
```

Taking in mind that this is a 2D array, how do I remove all elements from it?

I was thinking of using something like (for i in Num) but nothing came to mind

Comment: What do you mean by "remove all elements"? What is expected output?

Comment: It should be `Num[:] = []` otherwise you create a new object.

Comment: Can you post how you want this array to look like? I am assuming you want it to be Num = [ [].[].[]]  but you could want Num = [ ] also.  it is unclear

Comment: yeah just like you said @EdekiOkoh i want the array emty like [[][][]]

Comment: @Slam I want the list to look like [[],[],[]]

Comment: I think you should learn how computers handle variable, garbage collection, references. Unreachable data is automatically untracked by the garbage collector effectively making the memory accessible for other purposes.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte no you should not unless you understand that is creating a list with three references to the same list.

Comment: If there is a simpler solution then I would appreciate that if possible

Comment: Note, these are *lists* not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Num = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

for i in range(len(Num)):
    Num[i].clear()

print(Num)
```

This would output in:

```
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: I have modifications to the code again. Check now @karim Mousa

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for x in num:
    x.clear()
```

This will retain the original objects in `num`, i.e. no new objects are inserted. This might be critical if other objects keep references to those in `num` and would then run out of sync. For example:

```
num = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
ref = num[0]
num = [[] for __ in num]
print(ref)  # Still [1, 2, 3].
```

By using `x.clear()` on each element of `num` you ensure that any references stay synced:

```
num = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
ref = num[0]
for x in num:
    x.clear()
print(ref)  # Now [].
```

Comment: It works but I dont understated this part:     x[:] = []

Comment: @KarimMousa It's setting items from an empty, temporary list and hence clears all items in the original one. Anyway it's better to use `clear` , here the intention is much "clearer" and it doesn't need a temporary object.

Comment: yeah I think I got the point and it worked well in my code, thanks alot

Comment: wait a minute my output was []

Answer (score 2):

You can do a list-comprehension:

```
Num[:] = [[] for _ in Num]
```

This clears all elements still retaining empty lists without creating a new object.

`_` (underscore) is "I don’t care" field used as a throw away item.

Comment: You version with re-allocation (`[:]`) is actually slower for internal lists up to ~10**6 length. Just FYI.

Comment: @a_guest yeah, so?

Comment: @a_guest I think one can be charitable and assume they meant that the object referenced by `Num` is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with list comprehension:

`Num = [[] for _ in Num]`

Comment: can you give me a working example for something like this please?

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting you to get something like this:

`[[], [], []]`

To do that, you can do something like:

```
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
for i in range(len(b)):
     b[i] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner:

```
Num = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = [[] for i in Num]
print(result)
```

Output :

```
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: yeah this works fine thanks man! Il probably the .clear method I received earlier.